# Find maximum value of property in object of objects

Tags: javascript, loops, object, data-structures, max

I have an object like this:

```
const users = {
 adam: {
   age: 28,
   extraInfo: 'foobar',
 },
 brad: {
   age: 31,
   extraInfo: 'foobar',
 },
 jef: {
   age: 12,
   extraInfo: 'baarfoo',
 },
};
```

How can I check which object has the highest value of **"age"** property and get this object to a constant??

I've tried to use Object.keys(), throw data to Array and reduce but in the end, all these methods were not working as I wanted. I've been stuck on this issue for hours right now.

Comment: what should happen if you get two persons with same max age?

Comment: You can use [_.maxBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#maxBy)

Comment: @mpen I can't use any external library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce) function to find the object with the highest age.

Basically, the `reduce` function will loop the `users` object using its keys, and will be changing the accumulator according to the `age` value.

**The "key" of this solution is:**

```
const result = Object.keys(users). reduce((acc, curr) =>    
   acc.age ? (users[curr].age > acc.age ? users[curr] : acc) : users[curr], {});
```

**How this works:**

- [`Object.keys(users)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys): This function returns the array of keys from a specific object, in your case `["adam", "brad", "jef"]`.
- The `reduce` function will loop the Array of keys and will keep an `accumulator` (Current highest age) and a `currentValue` (Current item from source Array `Object.keys(users)`).
- `acc.age ? (users[curr].age > acc.age ? users[curr] : acc) : users[curr], {})` that condition evaluates the current values of `accumulator` and `currentValue`

  - Ask for `acc.age` because the `reduce` function starts with an empty initialValue `{}`:

    > Value to use as the first argument to the first call of the callback. If no initial value is supplied, the first element in the array will be used. Calling reduce() on an empty array without an initial value is an error.
  - If `acc.age` has a previous value then this condition `(users[curr].age > acc.age ? users[curr] : acc) : users[curr]` makes the swap between `accumulator`  and `currentValue` (Pick the highest age).

```js
const users = {
  adam: {
    age: 28,
    extraInfo: 'foobar',
  },
  brad: {
    age: 31,
    extraInfo: 'foobar',
  },
  jef: {
    age: 12,
    extraInfo: 'baarfoo',
  },
};

const result = Object.keys(users).reduce((acc, curr) =>    
       acc.age ? (users[curr].age > acc.age ? users[curr] : acc) : users[curr], {});

console.log(result)
```

**Solution suggested by [@irkeninvader](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1934920/irkeninvader) using `for-loop`:**

```js
const users = {
 adam: {
   age: 28,
   extraInfo: 'foobar',
 },
 brad: {
   age: 31,
   extraInfo: 'foobar',
 },
 jef: {
   age: 12,
   extraInfo: 'baarfoo',
 },
};

var maxAge;
for(var key in users){
  if(!maxAge || users[key].age > maxAge.age){
    maxAge = users[key];
  }
}

console.log('Highest Age is:');
console.log(maxAge);
```

Comment: looks good, +1.  Solution using loop if OP wants - https://jsfiddle.net/wt7q4gtt/

Comment: @IrkenInvader can I get your code and put it in this answer?  I will mention you.

Comment: Yeah sure, no problem.

Comment: Can U explain my please by writing pseudocode how does this line works:

Object.keys(users). reduce((acc, curr) =>    
       acc.age ? (users[curr].age > acc.age ? users[curr] : acc) : users[curr], {});

Answer (score 1):

You could take an array as result set for max age, because you could get more than one user with the same max age.

This proposal uses the keys of the object and iterates them and checks if the index is zero, or if the last result user has a smaller age than the actual user, then take a new array with the actual key as result.

If the age is equal, then append the actual user key to the result set. If not return the last result.

```js
const
    users = { adam: { age: 28, extraInfo: 'foobar' }, brad: { age: 31, extraInfo: 'foobar' }, jef: { age: 12, extraInfo: 'baarfoo' } },
    maxAge = Object
        .keys(users)
        .reduce((r, k, i) => !i || users[r[0]].age < users[k].age
            ? [k]
            : users[r[0]].age === users[k].age
                ? r.concat(k)
                : r, []);

console.log(maxAge);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   Here is code to find highest age object but I am not sure whether you can assign the result to a constant

  function highestAge( ageArray ) {
      var highest = null;
      for ( var key in ageArray ) {
            var val = ageArray[key];
             if( highest != null ) {
                 if ( highest.age < val.age ) {
                      highest = val;
                 }
             } else {
                 highest = val;
             }
           }
           return highest;
     }
```